# Show names for the same birthday MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

I am trying to get a query that shows the musicians who are born on the same day

I have the following table

### person

person_id
familyName
givenName
birthDate

This is the code I currently have

```
SELECT P.birthDate, DATE_FORMAT(birthDate,'%d %b %Y'), CONCAT(familyName, " ",givenName)
AS Person
FROM person P
WHERE givenName IS NOT NULL
AND familyName IS NOT NULL
AND birthDate IS NOT NULL
AND DATE_FORMAT(birthDate,'%d %b %Y') IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(birthDate,'%d %b %Y');
```

I cannot seem to figure out how to use a where or some other clause to do this.

Comment: You need to use `group by`. For example, `select birthdate, CONCAT(familyName, " ",givenName) from person group by birthdate order by birthdate asc;`

Comment: Please edit your question and show sample data and desired results.

Comment: By the way `concat(givenName, familyName, birthDate) is not null` have the same effect to your where clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some choices for you:

**1) Group by**

```
SELECT P.birthDate, DATE_FORMAT(birthDate,'%d %b %Y'), GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(familyName, " ",givenName)) AS PersonNames
  FROM person P
 WHERE concat( givenName, familyName, birthDate) IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY P.birthDate;
```

**2) Join**

```
SELECT P.person_id, P.birthDate, 
       DATE_FORMAT(P.birthDate,'%d %b %Y'), 
       CONCAT(P.familyName, " ",P.givenName) AS PersonName, 
       CONCAT(PB.familyName, " ",PB.givenName) AS OtherPersonName
  FROM person P
  LEFT JOIN person PB
    ON P.birthDate = PB.birthDate
 WHERE concat( P.givenName, P.familyName, P.birthDate) IS NOT NULL
   AND concat( PB.givenName, PB.familyName ) IS NOT NULL
 ORDER BY P.person_id,PB.person_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

**What is Group By**

The GROUP BY statement is used in conjunction with the aggregate functions to group the result-set by one or more columns.

**SQL GROUP BY Syntax**

```
SELECT column_name, aggregate_function(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name operator value
GROUP BY column_name;
```

In your case it will group all the musicians with same birth date where as birth date would be your column ,storing the date of birth of every musician. Hope it helps ...